# Inner function accessing variables directly from outer function scope - What are the drawbacks?

Tags: python

I saw this snippet in a code that I am working on. And I feel that accessing the outer function variable directly in the inner function brings some undesirable magic. For e.g. when I read the function, I assume that the variables I am manipulating in that function is gotten from the parameters

```
def outer_function():
    filename = os.path.abspath("some.config")

    def inner_function(state):
        with open(filename, "w+") as f:
            f.write(state)
            f.flush()
            os.fsync(f.fileno())
        os.rename(filename + ".ext" , filename)
```

- What are the drawbacks of inner_function accessing the variable `filename` directly from it's immediate outer scope?
- Are there any stylistic drawbacks/concerns in this snippet of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be fine in this case, since the interpreter will look in the enclosing scope of `inner_function` after failing to find `filename` in the local scope. However, there are some ways in which scope resolution can trip you up. For example, if you try and change `filename` within `inner_function` you'll run into problems like in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping).

It's not clear what you're doing with `os.rename(filename + ".ext" , filename)`. Your code doesn't create a `.ext` file, and if it renaming it would overwrite the file at `filename` anyways.